# Android:layout_toRightOf

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i am about to develop an apps, I am having some problem.
I wanna make my spinner and text view side by side.I hope u someone here can help me..TQ

```
editText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="5px" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:entries="@array/phone_arrays"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:prompt="@string/phone_prompt"
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Use a linearLayout (horizontal) and place your code(Spinner&editText) inside the layout...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MyActivity">


<editText
android:id="@+id/editText3"
android:layout_width="157dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
android:background="@drawable/round"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="number"
android:padding="5px" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".25"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
android:entries="@array/phone_arrays"
android:padding="0dip"
android:prompt="@string/phone_prompt"
</LinearLayout>
```